# How does Python bitshift opeartors translate to set_downstream and set_upstream functionality in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I want to understand how Python bitshift operators `>>` and `<<` are used for defining operator relationships in Airflow. I am not able to figure out the logic that can be used for translating the functionality of set_upstream() and set_downstream() methods using the bitshift operators. It will be helpful if someone can also point me to the relevant module in the Airflow code repo.

```
what makes       op1 >> op2 >> op3 << op4

equivalent to    op1.set_downstream(op2)
                 op2.set_downstream(op3)
                 op3.set_upstream(op4)
```

Comment: There's probably a magic method that allows classes to override the butthurt operator functions.

Comment: This is how its implemented: 

`def __rshift__(self, other):`
            `self.set_downstream(other)`
            `return other`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>` and `<<` are translated to the [`__lshift__`/`__rlshift__` and `__rshift__`/`__rrshift__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) of the relevant object.

Answer (score 1):

> It will be helpful if someone can also point me to the relevant module in the Airflow code repo.

The relevant module where it is defined is [*models.py*](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/51e4ad6e6472dbf42b5531952ea64058ac68836b/airflow/models.py#L2689), by the way. And the line of relevance is [where the `__rshift__`, `__lshift__`, `__rrshift__` and `__rlshift__` operators are defined](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/51e4ad6e6472dbf42b5531952ea64058ac68836b/airflow/models.py#L2689), which are the methods that `>>` and `<<` translate to.